# Liquidity transfer from A user to B user

Tags: web3js, javascript, uniswap, liquidity-provider, liquidity

How can I make option for user transfering his liquidity pool value (withdraw it) to user B? Maybe it’s uniswap router, transfering LP tokens from wallet or what?

Comment: You just need to transfer the Lp token

Comment: Hi! Please provide more detail/clarity in your question. Are you asking if it's possible to transfer the ownership of liquidity in an AMM pool without withdrawing the deposited funds? If so, which AMM? Thanks!

Comment: @TheRenaissance I mean transfer ownership of a uniswap provided liquidity from user A to user B. But instant withdraw to user B way also good (withdraw deposited + earned). How can I do these two solutions if it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LP Token acts as an ERC20 token. Therefore, transferring the liquidity pool value to User B is a straightforward process—similar to transferring any ERC20 token.

For example, you can achieve this by adding the LP Token to Metamask and executing a standard transfer to User B. Alternatively, you have the option to create a smart contract featuring a transferLPToken() function. When a user initiates this function, they seamlessly transfer their LP Tokens to User B.